# How to query Leads by multiple (logical-and) conditions?

Tags: marketo

is there a way to query Leads by multiple conditions using the REST API, similar to the SQL AND, or OR logical operators?

The close solution I found is:

> Get Leads by Filter Type:
>   http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/getLeadsByFilterUsingGET

That seems not capable of do multiple Filter Type?  For example, I want to query by firstName AND lastName.  How to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Why not creating a static list in Marketo and just use [Get Leads By List ID](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Static_Lists/getLeadsByListIdUsingGET_1)?

Comment: I don't quite understand the so-called "static list".  How do I get the static list id?  Is that something I need to create first?  Any more pointer for a marketo newbie to learn and understand your suggestion?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ha sorry. You'll need to login to your Marketo instance and insert the leads you want into a static list (see: [Understanding Static Lists](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Understanding+Static+Lists))

Comment: ummm ... thanks for the doc pointer.  I can see it can be very useful for many use cases.  But my objective is to query lead by firstname + lastname.  How do I setup a "static list" to support the query?

Comment: Yanir, do you still think your suggestion would work for my needs?  Any other suggestion or pointer are highly appreciated.